# How to get all the highest integers in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3]
```

Now I know how to get the highest integer:

```
max(numbers)
```

But this would only get 5. What I want it the two 5s in the list. Is there a way of getting all the highest integers in the list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
max_num = max(numbers)
highest = [num for num in numbers if num == max_num]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `max` to get the highest value, and then `count` on the list to get number of occurrences

```
m = max(numbers)
numbers.count(m)
res = [m] * numbers.count(m)
# [5, 5]
```

Comment: numbers.count(max(a))*str(max(a)) = '55', but there's no space

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list containing only the highest number:

```
maximum = max(numbers)
highest = list(filter(lambda x: x == maximum, numbers))
```

Comment: Isn't the interpreter smart enough to store the `max(numbers)` in a separate variable?

Comment: No. `max` is not guaranteed to be a pure function. Python allows *all kinds of crazy side-effects*, and is entirely too dynamic of a language for that sort of optimization.